# How to find point where an unlinear function equals zero

Tags: python, numpy, math, sympy

I have an unlinear function from neuroscience. `ad` is a parameter and t is the time.

```
def alpha(t, ad):
    if t < 0:
        return 0
    else:
        return pow(ad, 2) * t * np.exp(-1 * ad * t)
```

With `ad = 2` It rises from `x = 0`, increases to `0.7` and becomes near `0` at `x=3`.

I can find when this function is near or equal to 0 by iterating by intervals. But I just need to know where the function is near or equal to 0. I was wondering if there is any way to find it without iterating ex) intersecting with x = 0 function, or when derivative equals 0 ...

Answer (score 1):

I presume that you want to find when the derivative is equal to zero. You can do that with sympy:

```
In [12]: from sympy import exp, Symbol, nsolve

In [13]: ad = 2

In [14]: t = Symbol('t')

In [15]: f = pow(ad, 2) * t * exp(-1 * ad * t)

In [16]: f
Out[16]: 
     -2⋅t
4⋅t⋅ℯ    

In [17]: f.diff(t)
Out[17]: 
       -2⋅t      -2⋅t
- 8⋅t⋅ℯ     + 4⋅ℯ    

In [18]: solve(f.diff(t), t)
Out[18]: [1/2]
```

EDIT: Your answer below suggests a different question from the one in the OP so I'll update this:

You want to find the zeros of this:

```
In [5]: ad = Symbol('ad')

In [6]: t = Symbol('t')

In [7]: epsilon = Symbol('epsilon')

In [8]: f = pow(ad, 2) * t * exp(-1 * ad * t) - epsilon

In [9]: f
Out[9]: 
  2    -ad⋅t    
ad ⋅t⋅ℯ      - ε
```

We can solve this analytically using `solve`:

```
In [10]: sol, = solve(f, t)

In [11]: sol
Out[11]: 
  ⎛-ε ⎞ 
-W⎜───⎟ 
  ⎝ ad⎠ 
────────
   ad
```

This answer is given in terms of the Lambert W function. You can substitute for `ad` and `epsilon` to get the answer for any particular values:

```
In [12]: sol.subs({ad:2, epsilon:0.01})
Out[12]: 0.00251259459155665
```

This is giving you the root near zero though because it's branch W0 of the Lambert W function. The other root is given in by branch `W_{-1}` and is

```
In [32]: -LambertW(-epsilon/ad, -1)/ad
Out[32]: 
  ⎛-ε     ⎞ 
-W⎜───, -1⎟ 
  ⎝ ad    ⎠ 
────────────
     ad  

In [28]: (-LambertW(-epsilon/ad, -1)/ad).subs({ad:2, epsilon:0.01}).n()
Out[28]: 3.64199856754954
```

If you just want to solve for these numerically then you can use `nsolve`:

```
In [29]: nsolve(f.subs({ad:2, epsilon:0.01}), t, 0)
Out[29]: 0.00251259459155665

In [30]: nsolve(f.subs({ad:2, epsilon:0.01}), t, 1)
Out[30]: 3.64199856754954
```

Comment: This finds the local extremum of `f` at which the derivative is zero, which is the maximum of function `f`. But the OP is interested in the "near-zeroes" of function `f`, not its maximum.

Comment: The OP asked for zeros of a function that doesn't have any non-trivial zeros. Since they also mentioned "when derivative equals 0" I went with that

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find a solution using Oscar's answer.

1. The function was exponential, so it never reaches 0 after 0
2. I just pulled the function a bit with a minus epsilon
   (epsilon is user defined)
3. There will be two zeros, and I just need the second one.

```
from sympy import exp, Symbol, solve

epsilon = 0.01
ad = 2
t = Symbol('t')
f = pow(ad, 2) * t * exp(-1 * ad * t) - epsilon

print(solve([f], t, dict=True, quick=True))
#print(solve([t > 0, f], t, dict=True, quick=True)) i get an error if i use this
```

But this solution to finding a near-zero x took much more time than just iterating by interval of `0.01` over the function.

```
from sympy import exp, Symbol, solve, Piecewise
import numpy as np

epsilon = 0.01
ad = 2
t = Symbol('t')
f = pow(ad, 2) * t * exp(-1 * ad * t) - epsilon

#print(solve([f], t, dict=True, quick=True))

def alpha(t, ad):
    if t < 0:
        return 0
    else:
        return pow(ad, 2) * t * np.exp(-1 * ad * t)

def find(function, farg, arange, epsilon):
    xs = []
    for x in arange:
        if function(x, **farg) < epsilon:
            xs.append(x)
    return xs

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import timeit
    print(timeit.timeit("solve([f], t, dict=True)",
                            setup="from __main__ import solve, f, t",
                            number=100))
    print(timeit.timeit("solve([f], t, dict=True, quick=True)",
                            setup="from __main__ import solve, f, t",
                            number=100))
    print(timeit.timeit("find(alpha, {'ad':ad}, np.arange(0, 4, 0.01), 0.01)",
                            setup="from __main__ import find, alpha, ad , t, f, np",
                            number=100))
```

Outputs

```
24.860103617
24.020882552
0.10911201300000073
```

Comment: It doesn't really make sense to compare timings from an analytical and a numerical approach. Note that if ad and epsilon are symbols then `solve` can give you an analytic solution in terms of arbitrary values of ad and epsilon using the LambertW function. Then you can substitute any values you want to get an answer in less than a millisecond.